# .htaccess and proxy settings for routing a decoupled REST API consuming theme

Tags: theme-development, htaccess, api, rest-api, plugin-json-api

Developing a decoupled front-end consuming the REST API...

I'm using `create-react-app` so can enter a `proxy` field corresponding to WP in my `package.json` and write my calls like `fetch('/wp-json/v2/pages/...')` if I run `yarn start` from the front-end directory...

I'd love to actually have this theme in my `wp-content/themes/my-theme` directory though

I'm no `.htaccess` god

How can I make so that:

- Generic requests like `mysite.com/jibble/jabble` are handled by my SPA routing
- Protected routes like `mysite.com/wp-admin/*` and `mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/*` are still handled by Apache

Answer (score 0):

Ok this probably has a superfluous few lines but this works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/static/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```